# Unsupervised Image Segmentation based on object shape

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation, unsupervised-learning

Is there any unsupervised method ( i.e. not requiring a training dataset) to separate the objects on the figure below based on shape?[image]

I want to get something like that [image]
where the orange lines separate the elongated objects from the "round" ones

Comment: You could first separate the lines from the objects (maybe a opening operation could work) and then classify the objects based on volume, diameter etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

path = "Image.png"

image = cv2.imread(path, 0)
image_copy = deepcopy(image)
rad = 18
shape_type = cv2.MORPH_RECT
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(shape_type, (2 * rad + 1, 2 * rad + 1), (rad, rad))
image = cv2.dilate(image, element)
image_show = ~cv2.erode(image, element)


backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_copy, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)


contour, hier = cv2.findContours(image_show, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contour:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
    if (area > 12000) & (area / perimeter**2 * 4 * 3.14 > 0.3):
        blue = 0
        green = 0
        red = 255
    else:
        red = 0
        green = 0
        blue = 0
    cv2.drawContours(backtorgb, [cnt], 0, (blue, green, red), -1)


imS = cv2.resize(backtorgb, (960, 540))

cv2.imshow("image2", imS)
cv2.imwrite("output.png", backtorgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output:[image]